# RegEx for not allow space at starting and allow some special characters in middle

Tags: jquery, regex

At present I have this

```
^[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\s]+$
```

Expression but it allows special characters. I just want to allow these `[- .,$% ]` characters in middle.

Comment: Try [`^\S[a-zA-Z0-9.,$%\s-]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vP3tT0/3)

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-.,$% ][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```js
$('#input').on('input', function(i, v) {
  $(this).css('color', /^(?!((^[- .,$%].*)|(.*[- .,$%]$)))[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/.test(this.value) ? 'green':'red' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" />
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/sF5sD7/2)**

```
^(?!((^[- .,$%].*)|(.*[- .,$%]$)))[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @Ganesh please add valid and invalid strings

Answer (score 0):

This will not allow space & will also allowed mention special character

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-\[\]$%]*$
```

For allowing in between but not at starting

```
^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-_@./#&+-\[\]$%]+$
```

Comment: /^[^-\S][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-./&\[\]$%]+$/                                                                                                it is working but allowing all specials characters in the middle

Comment: so whats the actual issue now ? i mean where it should allow ?
that will be fine if u provide one valid and one invalid for reference string

Comment: White spaces should not allow at starting and only mentioned special characters should allow with white spaces in middle.

Comment: have u tried this ^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-_@./#&+-\[\]$%]+$ ?

share some valid n invalid string for comparison so i can run test cases

Comment: thanks for your response...test cases are 1.Text Box should not allow white space as starting..2.it should not allow other than [- .,$%]  these special characters.3.it should allow white space in middle.

Comment: Seem your not getting me fully, I asked you for sample strings, Both valid string and invalid string to run test using Regex pattern.